# Solve the polar coordinate integral $\int_{0}^{3\pi/2}\int_{1}^{4}(4-r)(2+\sin\theta)r dr d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am doing a certain problem and I ended up with the following...
$$\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\int_{1}^{4}(4-r)(2+\sin\theta)r dr d\theta$$

I am having a difficult time solving it. I did the following...

$$\int_{3\pi/2}^{\pi/2}[4r^2 +2r^2\sin\theta - (2/3)r^3 -(1/3)r^3\sin\theta]_{0}^{4}$$

$$\int_{3\pi/2}^{\pi/2}(54/3 - (37*\sin\theta)/3)d\theta$$

I have no idea how to proceed from here. How can I solve this?

Comment: $\frac {54}{3} \pi$

Comment: What are you having a problem with in the last integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\int_{1}^{4}(4-r)(2+\sin\theta)r dr d\theta\\
&=&\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\int_{1}^{4}(8r+4r\sin\theta-2r^2-r^2\sin\theta) dr d\theta\\
&=&\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}(4r^2+2r^2\sin\theta-\frac23r^3-\frac13r^3\sin\theta)\bigg|_{r=1}^{r=4} d\theta\\
&=&\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}(18+9\sin\theta)d\theta\\
&=&18\pi.
\end{eqnarray}